# Unable to add value in string array in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to add value in `students` array, but below code isn't working.

`js` code is --

```
angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.students=[
        'Scarlett Johansson','Jennifer Lawrence','Emma Stone','Kristen Stewart'
      ];  

      $scope.add = function(name){
        $scope.students.push(name);
      };
}]);
```

`html` code is --

```
<body ng-app="formExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p ng-repeat="stud in students">
      {{stud}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <input type='text' ng-model="name"/>
  <button ng-click="add(name);">add</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `button` and `input` are not included within the `div` `ng-controller="ExampleController"` scope.

```
<body ng-app="formExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p ng-repeat="stud in students">
      {{stud}}
    </p>

    <input type='text' ng-model="name"/>
    <button ng-click="add(name);">add</button>
  </div> <!-- close div here -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to push into `$scope.students` array, as there is no `students` array defined in the scope:

```
$scope.add = function(name) {
    $scope.students.push(name);
};
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i have tried with $scope.students.push(name); too but is not working, even function is not called

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.add = function(name) {

   $scope.students.push(name);//
};
```

Comment: thanks,  have tried with $scope.students.push(name); too but is not working, even function is not called